# Using jquery with java for HTML

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I've got a HTML website, in which there is some kind of data inside a table(I have no control in which way data is displayed on that website). I need to get/extract this table data.

i.e. nth row in the table has 2 columns, first columns text is "last update time", and the next column has some datestamp value. Using jquery I could say exactly that I want to get `this tables nth row second column text` which would give me some timestamp string.

Is there something like this in java, I will basically get the whole site and try to extract that information in the same manner as I described above. Does java have something similar?

Since javascript can be executed as a shell script as long as there is interpreter available, can something similar be done so that jquery functions are possible to invoke from java?

Answer (score 0):

I think [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Java can parse a DOM and you can interpret it that way.  For a brief explanation, check out http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom-document-object.html

Its certainly not going to be as simple as writing a jquery function to do the same.